# Explanation of Java print function output

Tags: java, recursion

```
  static void print(int i){
        if( i > 1){
            System.out.print("Y");
           print(i-1);
        }
        for(int t = 0; t < i ; t++){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
```

This code has the following output;
YY122333 with print(3);

However, I do not understand why. Why would the function start with printing a 1 anyway? Wouldnt it first pass the if function then print a Y followed by a solid 2?

M

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/18067711/1679863 to understand how recursion actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a special type of function called a **recursive function** meaning the function calls itself.

So the first time you call it (with a parameter greater than 1, I guess in your case it's 3), it prints `Y` then it calls the `print` function again with as parameter `i-1 (2)`

So, it goes again in the function, evaluates the condition and, as `i>1`, calls itself again with `1` as parameter this time.

It goes inside again but this time it's different, the first condition is false it jumps in the for loop which print `1` one time.

Then the function is resumed and the calling function will be taken back right where we left it (you remember, it's the same function with 2 as parameter). So it goes into the loop, prints `2` two times and resumes...

... to the first call of the function with 3 as parameter. So it goes in the loop and prints `3` three times.

Then the execution resumes to whatever function called the `print` function in the first place

Comment: Appreciate it Marc. Refreshing my recursive thinking is always good!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your sequence:

```
i = 3, call print(3-1)

    i = 2, call print(2-1)

        i = 1, don't call print as 1 > 1 == False
        for (int t=0; t<1; t++) prints '1'

    for (int t=0; t<2; t++) prints '2' two times

for (int t=0; t<3; t++) prints '3' three times
```

When code seems odd, it's always helpful to step through it with a debugger in an IDE like Eclipse, and watch variables change.

Answer (score 2):

Your algrothym is recursive. If you follow the logic of this in statements you have

```
static void print(int i){
    if( i > 1){
        System.out.print("Y");
       print(i-1);
    }
    for(int t = 0; t < i ; t++){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}

Call print(i==3)
i > 1 -> TRUE
Prints Y
Call print (i==2)
    i > 1 -> TRUE
    Prints Y
    Call print (i==1)
        i > 1 -> FALSE
        t = 0, t < 1 -> true
        print 0
        t = 1, t < 1 -> false
        return 
    t = 0, t < 2 -> true
    print 0
    t = 1, t < 2 -> true
    print 1
    t = 2, t < 2 -> false
    return
t = 0, t < 3 ->
and so on.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No, the code has a recursive call. The function calls itself in the function body: `print(i-1)`

Comment: Ah, I see it now! Thanks a lot. I guess they wanted to confuse the students after a few practices with recursion... how sneaky.

Comment: Oh ok, looks like you know what a recursive call is, my answer trying to explain it is useless then... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't. It's called recursion. When it finds an argument `i > 1`, it calls itself, waiting for that method to finish (printing everything else) and then continues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iteration   Step                        info                Output

1           enter print function        i==3
1           if (i>1)                    3 > 1 == true
1           System.out.print("Y")                           Y
1           call print functin with i-1 i - 1 == 2
2           enter print function        i==2
2           if (i>2)                    2 > 1 == true
2           System.out.print("Y")                           YY
2           call print function with i-1    i - 1 == 1
3           enter print function        i==1
3           if (i>1)                    1 > 1 == false
3           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==0; 0 < 1 == true
3           System.out.print(i)                             YY1
3           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==1; 1 < 1 == false
3           end iteration
2           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==0; 0 < 2 == true
2           System.out.print(i)                             YY12
2           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==1; 1 < 2 == true 
2           System.out.print(i)                             YY122
2           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==2; 2 < 2 == false
2           end iteration   
1           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==0; 0 < 3 == true
1           System.out.print(i)                             YY1223
1           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==1; 1<3 == true
1           System.out.print(i)                             YY12233
1           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==2; 2<3 == true
1           System.out.print(i)                             YY122333
1           for (t=0; t<i; t++)         t==3; 3<3 == false
1           end iteration
```