# What does StackOverflowError mean in Java? What is its fix?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm encountering the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Account.draw(Account.java:47)
```

This is the relevant section of code:

```
public double draw(double c) {
    if (c > 0) {
        return c;
    } else if (c < 0 && c > AccBalance) {
        AccBalance=-c;
        return AccBalance;
    }

    return draw(c);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It means you've recursed too deep and have [run out of space in the stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Comment: okay, so how do I fix it ?

Comment: It means neither your `if` or `else` blocks are executed, and `draw(c)` is called recursively, infinitely.

Comment: Oh, come on downvoter, this is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: You can fix it by ensuring your recursion stops at some point. As is, what happens if `c` is zero? Or if it's less than the account balance?

Comment: @Tenner I didn't down vote it, but I have no idea why it's being upvoted.  This question is easily google-able.

Comment: A StackOverflowError is Google-able, sure, but if you're new to programming like the submitter is, something like Wikipedia's first sentence, "In software, a stack overflow occurs when the stack pointer exceeds the stack bound" probably doesn't mean anything to you. We can still help the poor guy.

Comment: the fix of my code isn't -_-

Comment: How can I ensure that my recursion stops at some point? :(

Answer (score 4):

In your code, if `c == 0`, or `c <= AccBalance`, you keep on recursing the method with the same value of `c`. So, it will go into an infinite recursion, thus filling up the stack.

For each method invocation, a stack frame is allocated from the stack. Thus your code will end up allocating complete stack memory.

So, for e.g, if you call this method first time with `c = 0`, this is how the stack grows:

```
draw(0)
  draw(0)
    draw(0)
      draw(0)
        .. so on
```

You keep on passing `0` as argument, which doesn't satisfy any of your base cases.

As to how to solve this, we don't really have enough context to find out what should go in place of `return draw(c);`. But certainly that shouldn't be there. Perhaps `return draw(++c);`?? But we can only guess.

**See also:**

- [Recursion: Behind the Scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067711/1679863)

Comment: How do I stop this infinite recursion ?

Comment: @AbdulMoeed. Read my last two lines.

Comment: @AbdulMoeed Are you going to tell us what that method is supposed to do? At least write a problem statement there. Currently this issue cannot be resolved.

Comment: @AbdulMoeed You are going to have to explain what this `draw` method is _supposed_ to do. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

You're continually calling the `draw()` method. So you call the `draw()` method, then it calls the `draw()` method, then it calls the `draw()` method, then it calls the `draw()` method, et cetera, until you have no more memory left.

Check your `return` statement at the end. What do you want to return in that case? Right now it just keeps calling `draw()` again, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion.  StackOverflowError means your call stack got too deep - too many nested functions called without completing any of them - which recursion tends to do.